# wallet.dat size in Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet.dat, bip32-hd-wallets

Just created a new wallet using Bitcoin Core v0.15.1 (Windows x64), encrypted it with a password, and created one receiving address. The size of this wallet is 1 Mb.

In comparison, my old wallet, with about a dozen receiving addresses and transactions, encrypted using the password of the exact same length, is only 100 Kb.

I thought the 1 Mb is too large and suspicious. What could be the reason for this size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default size of the keypool was raised from 100 keys to 2x 1000 keys.

This was done in order to reduce the cases where recovery of a backup needs to decrypt the wallet to generate further keys.